# How do I manipulate the heuristics of the RShiny Slider to properly display small ranges without duplicate intermediate labels?

Tags: r, shiny

I've been trying to use the RShiny slider to display a small range (eg. 2013-2017) and the slider is showing duplicate labels for my range and has missing ticks.

[every_year_in_the_slider_displaying_multiple_times_and_missing_tick_marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aJ1S.png%5D)

Previously, I had added in the months to the slider to reduce the available space provided so that the duplications reduce, but I removed it since it didn't solve the problem completely and because it would add more confusion to the end user as I also have a separate months slider in my application.

I also didn't want to include `ticks = FALSE` because it gets rid of the intermediate labels altogether, which is not what I was looking for.

I have used `tags$style(type = "text/css", ".irs-grid-pol {display: none;}")` as was answered in another similar StackOverflow question to get rid of the displaying tick marks as to clean up the aesthetics:
[slider_without_ticks_with_dup_labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ3d2.png), but it still has duplicating labels that I cannot fix.

I couldn't find anything in the `shinywidgets` package to help me with this particular problem.

The simple version of what I'm using so far is:

```
tags$style(type = "text/css", ".irs-grid-pol {display: none;}"),
sliderInput(inputId = "Date",
              label = "Choose The Year",
              min = as.Date("2013","%Y"),
              max = as.Date("2017","%Y"),
              value=as.Date("2013", "%Y"),
              timeFormat="%Y"
  )
```

Ideally, I would like to have the ticks showing with equal spacing and unique labels for the slider, but I don't know what to do at this point.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try with adding `step = 365`. This should give you steps of 365 days or approx. 1 year.

Comment: Thank you very much @stefan! This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Stefan answered the question I've spent way too much time on! Adding step = 365, i.e.

```
sliderInput(inputId = "Date",
          label = "Choose The Year",
          min = as.Date("2013","%Y"),
          max = as.Date("2017","%Y"),
          value=as.Date("2013", "%Y"),
          timeFormat="%Y", 
          step = 365
```

)

allows for an even step size where we can keep the tick marks and the labels!

EDIT: However, the step size won't change if it is added during the server portion of the application (when using `updateSliderInput()`), so might have to rearrange the application accordingly. Additionally, when expanding the page, the tick marks may still be wonky, so having the css line in my question would still be recommended for a clean design.